# Brand activation feature on Product page

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product

How to do Brand activation feature on Product page in magento?

When I click on one product, that product page opened. When I click brand under product name, it is not working.

It must show all products related to that brand name.

Please help me urgent.

Comment: In Which Magento 1.x or 2.x @Dipak Kumar

Comment: Are You Using the extension ha For showing Brands?

Comment: 2.0 magento

I am not using any extension

Comment: U can use free extension @Dipak Kumar

Comment: give me name of free extension. I am not getting

Comment: check my site http://www.shreehardwares.com/garden-tools/makita-lawn-mower-elm3711.html

Comment: NOT WORKING 
when i am clicking on MAKITA. it must open new page containing all products of MAKITA brand

Comment: how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the code of page-title in html anchor tag like given link below[image]